# C++/STL: XOR of two set

Tags: c++, stl

Given two STL sets, I want to find out the XOR of them. Is there an easy, pre-existing way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::set_symmetric_difference`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_symmetric_difference.html) from the C++ standard library.

Comment: Apparently you won the race :p

Comment: @Matthieu:  By a whopping 32 seconds!  (Actually, I hadn't returned to see that two others had posted the same thing, otherwise I'd have probably deleted this :-P)

Answer (score 1):

Yes: [`std::set_symmetric_difference`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference/)

Answer (score 1):

Try std::set_symmetric_difference:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference/